# How can I specify PATH env var in fish shell in a declarative command

Tags: bash, environment-variables, fish

I want my `$PATH` environment variable to specifically contain 3 specific directories and nothing else.

I don't want to use individual **ADD** and **REMOVE** commands to shape my $PATH variable.

In Bash I can just say `PATH="aaa:bbb:ccc"`

But I haven't found a way to do that in fish shell. OR I'm missing some syntax.

The Fish tutorial also doesn't cover this. It only mentions iterative approaches (add/remove from path)

What command can I add to my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `set` with the `-gx` together because it is a shorthand to define a global variable and export it to the environment in a single command, so for example you can save it into this path `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

```
set -gx PATH "/path/to/test1" "/path/to/test2" "/path/to/test3"
```

don't forget to restart your shell or run `source ~/.config/fish/config.fish` for the changes to take effect!

Comment: Turns out you have to double quote paths with spaces. That's what kept breaking for me. 
I suggest add that little tidbit into your answer for future google hunters that end up here